# How to use 2 parameters for apply-method in pandas

Tags: pandas

| a | b | c (2*a) | d (a+b) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | 2*a1 | ???? |
| a2 | b2 | 2*a2 | ???? |

I don't know how to calculate the column 'd(a+b)' which is used ***2 parameters*** with apply method.

If I want the value of column 'c'(=2*a) which is only 1 parameter, I will script the following code.

```
def function(x):
    ret = 2*x
    return ret

df['c'] = df['a'].apply(function)
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your method in lambda.

```py
def function(a, b):
    ret = a + b
    return ret

df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: function(row['a'], row['b']), axis=1)
```

Or

```py
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['a'] + row['b'], axis=1)
```

Simply adding two columns is also ok

```py
df['d'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

Answer (score 0):

df.apply(np.sum, axis=1) will sum all elememts of row